# Showing 2 users with reputation +2000 in area51 proposal board while there is only one, case of a less-then-90-days beta proposal?

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51

In [Arabic Proposal in Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language), it shows that there are 2 users with reputation greater then 2000 while in reality there is only one:

[image: area51 arabic 13 avid users]

[image]

It seems that it is also wrong for 200+ rep: showing 22 users where  there are only 13.

I checked the accepted answer for the question [How are the “on pace for” metrics on Area 51 generated and are they being done so correctly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123554/how-are-the-on-pace-for-metrics-on-area-51-generated-and-are-they-being-done-s) but it didn't explain the case of a less-then-90-days beta proposal? The other answer do, but letting the explanation why wrong open.

Comment: It's probably related to it saying "on pace for at 90 days" and I was going to post an answer to that effect, although for the second highest rep user 604 / 31 days  * 90 = 1754 so it seems there must be more to it than a simple ratio so it'd be good to see an official answer on how it's calculated.

Comment: @santiago, I think the accepted answer there dont explain the case of less-than-90-days beta site, the second answer explain that it is wrong but no official answer they keep it that way?

Comment: Maybe it is one of the many secret algorithms