# "on pace for ... users at 90 days" - how are these statistics calculated?

Tags: support, area-51, statistics

From [Literature's Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature):

[image: Screenshot with "on pace for ..." stats highlighted]

How does the system extrapolate from the existing userbase how many users there are likely to be with at least a certain rep score in forty days' time? I can think of a few possible algorithms none of which make much sense. Has the algorithm used ever been made public?

(I've seen [this [bug] report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123554/278659) from 2012, but I don't think this is a duplicate. The old meta post has a lot of guesses at possible algorithms, but nothing is confirmed.)

Comment: [Unanswered since 2011.](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1942/how-is-on-pace-calculated)